# Synchronous Interruptible Wait

Tags: c#, asynchronous, websocket

On an ASP.NET C# page, I have an asynchronous `initialAction` that needs to performed.

`initialAction` involves the server sending a message over a WebSocket, and the server should wait for a while until the client responds.  Once it responds, it should call `onComplete`.  I already have this part finished.

If the action does not complete its work in 5 seconds (for example), I want the script to move on.  Currently, I make my script wait in a Task by repeatedly sleeping and checking a `CancellationTokenSource`.  If the `CancellationTokenSource` is canceled by `onComplete` or if 5 seconds has elapsed, the script will continue.

The below is the best method I've found.  Is there a better way?

```
public static string wait(Action<Action<string>> initialAction)
{
    string message = null;
    using (CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
    {
        Action<string> onComplete = (msg) =>
        {
            message = msg;
            tokenSource.Cancel();
        };
        Task sleepTask = new Task(() =>
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            while (true)
            {
                if (tokenSource.IsCancellationRequested ||
                    stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > 5000) { break; }
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }, tokenSource.Token);
        initialAction(onComplete);
        sleepTask.Start();
        sleepTask.Wait();
    }
    return message;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's way easier than you're making it out to be.  First off, just put the timeout into the constructor of the cancellation token source to have it time out after a period of time.

Then to just wait until the token is cancelled just grab the token's wait handle and wait on it rather that creating a task to do a spinwait on it.

```
public static string wait(Action<Action<string>> initialAction)
{
    string message = null;
    using (CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(5000))
    {
        initialAction(msg =>
        {
            message = msg;
            tokenSource.Cancel();
        });
        tokenSource.Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne();
    }
    return message;
}
```

Just be aware that in both code snippets the "aborted" action is still continuing on; it's not stopped, we just stop waiting for it and return `null`.

Comment: Wow.  Awesome, @Servy.  Regarding your last sentence, should I check `tokenSource.IsCancellationRequested` within the delegate function?

Comment: @user1325179 It depends; the whole point is to ensure that you know what's going on in that action, and that you are aware of the consequences of it continuing on.  Is it a CPU intensive operation?  If so, it may be using up CPU cycles for some time.  Is it performing side effects that are going to be observed later on in code (which I really hope it's not) then you need to be prepared for that.  Perhaps the caller of this needs to act differently if the action is cancelled, but more likely you just need to use actions that won't wreak havoc if they are still doing work after cancellation.

Comment: When I was asking about "the delegate function," I meant the delegate which does this:  `message=msg;tokenSource.Cancel();`.  So should I avoid setting `message` or cancelling `tokenSource` if the program has moved on already?

Comment: I guess I should have used the "at" notation in my last comment, @Servy.  Hopefully you'll be notified of this one.  Please see my previous comment.  Thank you.

Comment: @user1325179 No.  It really won't matter what you do at that point if the token has already been cancelled.  Setting `message` doesn't really hurt or help, since it'll never be read again.  Cancelling an already cancelled token, again, doesn't really do anything, or hurt anything.